# Why does java.awt.Dimension have public variables?

Tags: java, awt

Isn't it true that a class with `public` variables is considered weak in Encapsulation and is it not a bad design practice?

If such is the case why does `java.awt.Dimension` have 2 public variables `width` and `height`?

Comment: I think even if it does have such public fields  one should use getters.

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas :ya... but what is the reason behind making the variables public?

Comment: IMHO, you'll have to ask the original author

Comment: `java.awt.Dimension` has been around since 1.0, so my guess would be backwards compatibility.

Comment: We should ask developer that has written java.awt.Dimension :), i think

Comment: @Obicere : but when java 1.0 was created it was created as an Object Oriented Programming Language, was it not? then why did they made it public in 1.0 itself?

Comment: @RC. : I agree.. but i have no idea who the author is and i believe i get better answers here.. :)

Comment: Sami Shaio and Arthur van Hoff were the authors :)

Comment: @BlackPanther conventions have changed. They can't change the system without breaking potentially massive amounts of code that *should* be backwards compatible.

Comment: @ashatte how did you look up for the authors?

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas I saw it is listed [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Dimension.java) and [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/apidocs/java.awt.Dimension.html)

Comment: @ashatte thank  you, that's what i was asking for:)

Comment: @ashatte : thk you for the link on the authors... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that exposing public fields is not a violation of encapsulation itself. Encapsulation is the property of entities, that hide inside themself a complex inner structure. This complex structure can't be accessed directly and therefore not being risked to be broken. It is accessed only through public methods, which make their work well and don't corrupt the complex inner structure. For example, we don't have access to `HashMap`'s hashtable directly and we can't corrupt it. We only use `get` and `put` methods, that care of hashtable state properly. But where is the complex structure of `Dimension` object? What things get broken when we just write `d.width = 23`?

I think there are reasons to use public getters/setters instead of public fields in this case: taste and conventions. The latter is more significant, I suppose. But it also depends on where and for what we apply this conventions.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thank you very much for making it clear. Instead blaming it as a pretty old code, you have explained the purpose of a getter and setter. +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

Dimension has been around for a really long time and in the early days of Java there was a real concern about performance.  So they used public variables and made it mutable - two major mistakes, just to gain a few clock cycles.

All you guys asking questions about premature optimizations can learn a good lesson here.
(Added)

Dimensions change a lot (as a window is resized) and by making it mutable you "save" on having to allocate new objects - just reuse the old one.  Which, in the early days of Java, made some sense.  Plus, they got accessed a lot as the GUI drew nested Buttons within Components inside Frames, so, to save a few cycles in a redraw don't use a function call.  Again, makes a little sense.

The problem is that nowadays with all the multi-core processors and multi-threaded code you often en up making defensive copies of a Dimension.  Losing all that "advntage", plus, annoying and a source of bugs.

Comment: thx for the response.. :) but i am having a doubt are you saying that at the earlier stage the Dimension had `public final height`? i'm sorry if my question sounds absurd, but i can't think of anything else than `final` to make a field immutable.

Comment: I had a typo in my first edit.  The class has always been mutable, with non-final fields, to "save" on object creation.  IMO, they _should_ have made the class immutable with final variables.

Comment: i just found this [**link**](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/apibook/javag9.htm) provided by @ashatte, in it `java.awt.Color` has `public final` variables. And i believe both `Dimension` and `Color` are coded at the same time, why did they not make it final in `Dimension`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the JavaDoc for Dimension:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html

You will see that the public fields have been there since 1.0 (1996).  The language has evolved to accomodate many principles and best practices over time to become the language that it is today.  This included a reworking of the AWT model for the 1.1 release, of which the accessors and mutators where added for these fields.

Here are some archived release notes for the JDK 1.1 release:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/awt/HowToUpgrade.html

From which this is quoted:

> "These changes make it possible for programs such as GUI builders and
>   JavaBeans-using programs to query components to determine the
>   components' properties."

Comment: thank you for the response. but if you could look at this [**link**](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/apibook/javag9.htm), you can see that the `java.awt.Color` was released along with the `Dimension` class and it has mutators available. Then why is it that `Dimension` is not having variables as `final`?

Comment: The java.awt.Color fields are static and the Dimension fields are not.  The matter as to why the java.awt.Color methods are public is an entirely different question.